# Property Object Javascript is not set with Jquery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have following code:

```
function cBase() {   

}

function Setting() {
    this.myvar='';
}

Setting.prototype = new cBase();
Setting.prototype.setVal=function() { 
    var deferred=$.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.myvar='my value';
        console.log('value '+this.myvar);
        deferred.resolve();
    },2000);

    return deferred.promise();
};


var oset=new Setting();   
oset.setVal().done(function(){
    console.log('all done '+oset.myvar);
});
```

Property `myvar` previously is set with value `"my value"`, but when I use object `oset` and call method `setVal()`, property `myvar` is empty? Why does this happen?

Comment: You are setting the value in the wrong context. Just do `var _that = this; setTimeout(function(){
                    _that .myvar='my value';` and it should be fine. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boz8Lyrn/)

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` will not be your object inside the `setTimeout()` callback.  You will need to either use `.bind()` to ensure `this` is what you want or you another variable to save it.

```
Setting.prototype.setVal=function() { 
    var deferred=$.Deferred();
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.myvar='my value';
        console.log('value '+self.myvar);
        deferred.resolve();
    },2000);

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Remember that `this` is determined by the caller of a function by who it is called.  For a normal function call which is what `setTimeout()` does when it calls its callback function, `this` is set to the global object (in regular mode) or to `undefined` (in strict mode).